# Syntax error 1084 whatever i do

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax

I am trying to make a tool for a game...
Pushing a button gives some results after calculations. The Code is not finished yet but it does not have to give errors. Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
//-----------------------variables------------------------

var iPPP1:String;
var iPPP2:String;
var iPPP3:String;
var iPPP4:String;
var iPPP5:String;
var iPPP6:String;
var iPPP7:String;
var iCntbonus:String;
var iRawPrice:String;
var iAverSal:String;
var iTax:String;
var iNoC7:String;
var iNoC6:String;
var iNoC5:String;
var iNoC4:String;
var iNoC3:String;
var iNoC2:String;
var iNoC1:String;
var iEm7:String;
var iEm6:String;
var iEm5:String;
var iEm4:String;
var iEm3:String;
var iEm2:String;
var iEm1:String;
var iRaw5:String;
var iRaw4:String;
var iRaw3:String;
var iRaw2:String;
var iRaw1:String;
var apotelesma:Number;
var bonus:Number;
var i1:Number;
var i2:Number;
var i3:Number;
var i4:Number;
var i5:Number;
var i6:Number;
var i7:Number;

//------------------------restricts------------------------

PPP1.restrict = "0-9\\.";
PPP2.restrict = "0-9\\.";
PPP3.restrict = "0-9\\.";
PPP4.restrict = "0-9\\.";
PPP5.restrict = "0-9\\.";
PPP6.restrict = "0-9\\.";
PPP7.restrict = "0-9\\.";
Cntbonus.restrict = "0-5";
RawPrice.restrict = "0-9\\.";
AverSal.restrict = "0-9\\.";
Tax.restrict = "0-9";
NoC7.restrict = "0-9";
NoC6.restrict = "0-9";
NoC5.restrict = "0-9";
NoC4.restrict = "0-9";
NoC3.restrict = "0-9";
NoC2.restrict = "0-9";
NoC1.restrict = "0-9";
Em7.restrict = "0-9";
Em6.restrict = "0-9";
Em5.restrict = "0-9";
Em4.restrict = "0-9";
Em3.restrict = "0-9";
Em2.restrict = "0-9";
Em1.restrict = "0-9";
Raw5.restrict = "0-9";
Raw4.restrict = "0-9";
Raw3.restrict = "0-9";
Raw2.restrict = "0-9";
Raw1.restrict = "0-9";

//-------------------------------borders----------------------------

PPP1.border = true;
PPP2.border = true;
PPP3.border = true;
PPP4.border = true;
PPP5.border = true;
PPP6.border = true;
PPP7.border = true;
Cntbonus.border = true;
RawPrice.border = true;
AverSal.border = true;
Tax.border = true;
NoC7.border = true;
NoC6.border = true;
NoC5.border = true;
NoC4.border = true;
NoC3.border = true;
NoC2.border = true;
NoC1.border = true;
Em7.border = true;
Em6.border = true;
Em5.border = true;
Em4.border = true;
Em3.border = true;
Em2.border = true;
Em1.border = true;
Raw5.border = true;
Raw4.border = true;
Raw3.border = true;
Raw2.border = true;
Raw1.border = true;

//--------------------------calculations-------------------------------
calc_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Calco);

function Calco(event:MouseEvent):void;
{
iPPP1 = PPP1.text;
iPPP2 = PPP2.text;
iPPP3 = PPP3.text;
iPPP4 = PPP4.text;
iPPP5 = PPP5.text;
iPPP6 = PPP6.text;
iPPP7 = PPP7.text;
iCntbonus = Cntbonus.text;
iRawPrice = RawPrice.text;
iAverSal = AverSal.text;
iTax = Tax.text;
iNoC7 = NoC7.text;
iNoC6 = NoC6.text;
iNoC5 = NoC5.text;
iNoC4 = NoC4.text;
iNoC3 = NoC3.text;
iNoC2 = NoC2.text;
iNoC1 = NoC1.text;
iEm7 = Em7.text;
iEm6 = Em6.text;
iEm5 = Em5.text;
iEm4 = Em4.text;
iEm3 = Em3.text;
iEm2 = Em2.text;
iEm1 = Em1.text;
iRaw5 = Raw5.text;
iRaw4 = Raw4.text;
iRaw3 = Raw3.text;
iRaw2 = Raw2.text;
iRaw1 = Raw1.text;
i1 = (parseInt(iEm1) + parseInt(iNoC1)) * 10 * bonus;
i2 = (parseInt(iEm2) + parseInt(iNoC2)) * 10 * bonus;
i3 = (parseInt(iEm3) + parseInt(iNoC3)) * 10 * bonus;
i4 = (parseInt(iEm4) + parseInt(iNoC4)) * 10 * bonus;
i5 = (parseInt(iEm5) + parseInt(iNoC5)) * 10 * bonus;
i6 = (parseInt(iEm6) + parseInt(iNoC6)) * 10 * bonus;
i7 = (parseInt(iEm7) + parseInt(iNoC7)) * 10 * bonus;

if (parseInt(iCntbonus) == 0) {
    bonus = 1;
} else if (parseInt(iCntbonus) == 1) {
    bonus = 1,2;
} else if (parseInt(iCntbonus) == 2) {
    bonus = 1,4;
} else if (parseInt(iCntbonus) == 3) {
    bonus = 1,6;
} else if (parseInt(iCntbonus) == 4) {
    bonus = 1,8;
} else {
    bonus = 2;
}

// υπολογισμός εσόδων
apotelesma = (Number(iRawPrice)*bonus*parseInt(iRaw1)*35)+(Number(iRawPrice)*bonus*parseInt(iRaw2)*70)+(Number(iRawPrice)*bonus*parseInt(iRaw3)*125)+(Number(iRawPrice)*bonus*parseInt(iRaw4)*175)+(Number(iRawPrice)*bonus*parseInt(iRaw5)*250)

apotelesma = apotelesma + (i1 * Number(iPPP1)) - (i1 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + (i2 * Number(iPPP2)) - (i2 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + (i3 * Number(iPPP3)) - (i3 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + (i4 * Number(iPPP4)) - (i4 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + (i5 * Number(iPPP5)) - (i5 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + (i6 * Number(iPPP6)) - (i6 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + (i7 * Number(iPPP7)) - (i7 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100)
apotelesma.toString()
}
```

I have problem with the last 3 lines...

Comment: Aaaah!!  Use arrays!  In a `for`-loop, use getChildByName("Raw" + i)` and assign the data as a number into an array entry, so you don't `parseInt()` everywhere; you will also get rid of all the `String` variables as well.  And the calculations should be changed into `for`-loops as well.  You really need to take an introductory computer science course, or similar online tuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some very long calculations, and are missing atleast 5 closing parenetheses. I pasted the 2nd to the last line (the one that starts with `apotelesma = apotelesma`) into a text editor and counted the numbers of opening/closing parentheses.

The calculation is so long, it's not immediately clear where they should be inserted.  I would break down the calculations so that they are more readable. Anyone maintaining this code after you will benefit from the clarity.

Either break the long calculations up into many smaller ones, or just add line breaks in the code so it's clear what you're trying to do, like this:

```
apotelesma = apotelesma +
    (i1 * Number(iPPP1)) -
    (i1 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + // NOTE: you seem to be missing a closing paren here
    (i2 * Number(iPPP2)) -
    (i2 * (parseInt(iTax) / 100) + // and here... (and so on)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks man... Now I have new problem...

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 114 1126: Function does not have a body.

It seems that the function has a problem...

Comment: It's the semicolon character `;` at the end of your function declaration, you should remove it: `function Calco(event:MouseEvent):void;`